# R - extracting data from certain date or time period from a dataframe

Tags: r

i am new to R and I have a dataframe like this:

```
     EndDate EndId EndTime
1 02/01/2013   251   13:32
2 03/01/2013   251   17:19
3 04/01/2013   251   16:26
4 04/01/2013   368   08:36
5 05/01/2013   386   16:58
6 01/01/2013   329   11:51
```

How to select rows of the dataframe which lies between 03/01/2013 and 05/01/2013? (or for a certain time period?) Thanks

Comment: `Df[Df$EndDate>=as.Date("03/01/2013","%m/%d/%Y") & Df$EndDate<=as.Date("05/01/2013","%m/%d/%Y"),]` or `subset(Df,EndDate>=as.Date("03/01/2013","%m/%d/%Y") & EndDate<=as.Date("05/01/2013","%m/%d/%Y"))` are two (of many) options. This is assuming `EndDate` is already a `Date` class column of your data.frame `Df`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please please don't use ambiguous date formats. All 6 of your date strings are ambiguous; they could be dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. If you have control over the generation of the input data, please generate it in yyyy-mm-dd ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) form. It hurts my eyes to see ambiguous date formats.

Also, R has a builtin Date class, which is perfect for your purposes. Your EndDate column is not of Date type, which is discernible because R always prints Dates in ISO 8601 format. You can convert the column to Date type directly with this:

```
df$EndDate <- as.Date(df$EndDate, '%m/%d/%Y' );
```

(I've assumed mm/dd/yyyy format.)

Then you can use vectorized comparison, logical, and indexing operations to extract the subset of the data.frame that matches your criteria:

```
df[df$EndDate>=as.Date('2013-03-01') & df$EndDate<=as.Date('2013-05-01'),];
```

Answer (score 5):

My inclination would be to turn this into an `xts` (eXtensible Time Series) object and use time-series indexing on that.

```
library(xts)
df.xts <-xts(df["EndId"],order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(df$EndDate,df$EndTime),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))

df.xts["2013-03-01::2013-05-01"]
#                     EndId
# 2013-03-01 17:19:00   251
# 2013-04-01 08:36:00   368
# 2013-04-01 16:26:00   251
# 2013-05-01 16:58:00   386
```